# I can not make a file get contents link m3u8

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I can not do `file_get_contents` to a m3u8 link, I need it to then make a `str_replace` in its content, the m3u8 is downloaded without problems from the browser

```
<?php $url="https://neunlds120dal.akamaized.net/nlds/univisionnow2/univision_mia/as/live/univision_mia_hd_3000_pc.m3u8"; $url2= file_get_contents($url);  echo $url2; >
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you also get a "_failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden_" on that url? Also, you're missing a `?` at the end: `?>`

Comment: no error message appears, just do not download anything

Comment: Turn on debugging and show error messages, maybe also paste that URL in your browser to see if it's valid

Comment: shows the following error  http://prntscr.com/jeomdr  ,
the link is active and I can download the m3u8 from the browser

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: You get an error "_403 Forbidden_" which means you are not allowed to access the page. You might have cookies set that make the browser request valid. Calling it via browser returns a "_An error occurred while processing your request._" for me

Answer (score -1):

Note that [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) does not work with HTTPS well, try using cURL. For example:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://neunlds120dal.akamaized.net/nlds/univisionnow2/univision_mia/as/live/univision_mia_hd_3000_pc.m3u8");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

Comment: `<?php 
$url ='https://neunlds120dal.akamaized.net/nlds/univisionnow2/univision_mia/as/live/univision_mia_hd_1200_pc.m3u8';

$ch = curl_init();    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-G920V Build/MMB29K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.98 Mobile Safari/537.36");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
?>`